# Futter: Cannot find 'kGADAdSizeBanner' in scope

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-ios

Error on iOS:

```
Cannot find 'kGADAdSizeBanner' in scope
```

Line:

```
private var adSize: GADAdSize = kGADAdSizeBanner
```

Package:

```
native_admob_flutter
```

Extra info:

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.10.0, on macOS 11.6.2 20G314 darwin-x64, locale en-GB)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 13.2.1)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 2020.3)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.62.0)
[✓] Connected device (2 available)
[✓] HTTP Host Availability

• No issues found!
```

Android works.
Official Flutter package for ads (google_mobile_ads) is totally dead so changing to that one is not an option anymore.

Comment: Some part of this answer would be helpful for you > https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/8098

Comment: but it says "This issue is now specifically about Native Ads from Facebook and AdMob."

Comment: I just came across the exact issue, I forked the repo and did some minor migration so it can fit the latest Mobile Ads SDK (iOS). Hope it helps:
https://github.com/nathan1658/native_admob_flutter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this will help but I faced this same issue. So I looked at the Banner-Ad size section from their [documentation](https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/banner#banner_sizes), and just made a custom GADAdsize var.

For example if you wanted a Large Banner(kGADAdSizeLargeBanner), then the documentation shows that the size in points (Width x Height) is 320x100.

Size for whatever reason we can't access the variable kGADAdSizeLargeBanner (or kGADAdSizeBanner in your case) we can just create our own.

```
let adSize = GADAdSizeFromCGSize(CGSize(width: 320, height: 100))
```

Then using this adSize variable we can initialize a banner view.

```
let bannerView: GADBannerView = GADBannerView(adSize: adSize)
```

More detailed info about GADAdSizeFromCGSize can be found at this [link](https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/api/reference/Functions).

Comment: for my case I use that package that should covers already that implementation. I don't create the banner, like that, only call the method to import them

Answer (score 18):

See [docs](https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/banner#banner_sizes)
, you just need to remove the 'k' at the beginning because they update it for the iOS SDK.
From: kGADAdSizeBanner to GADAdSizeBanner.

Comment: OP, this is the best answer. You should designate it as such.